# How to archive live streams video as on-demand

Tags: http-live-streaming, flash-media-server

I stream any video for my users on the Lan network through Flash Media Server4.5 and my users can to view this videos on HTTP live stream. ([alink]http://192.168.1.10/live-video1.f4m[/alik]).
Now I need to save and archive this videos after unpublished until users can to play on-demand videos.

please advise me.
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

.f4m suggests that you are using HTTP Dynamic Streaming (HDS) rather than HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). The most popular way to download HDS streams is to use this script: https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/wiki